# How to write case statement in mongoDb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here I am using mongoose for my Mean application which consists of nodejs, expressjs and angularjs.

My problem here is I need to use different find conditions and according send the error message or data

Now I am using as below

```
User.findOne({ Email: req.body.Email }, (err, user) => {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (!user) {
                    return res.json("Account with that email address does not exist.");
                }
```

mongoose schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    FirstName: String,
    LastName: String,
    Email: { type: String, unique: true },
    UserName: String,
    Password: String,
    PhoneNumber: String,
    EmailVerified : Boolean,
    AdminApproved : Boolean   
}, { versionKey: false });
```

but now I had fields like email verified and adminapproved.

In Ms-Sql i used case statement like

1. where (Email not present) then `show Email not exist`
2. where (Email present and not email verified ) then `show please verify email`
3. where (Email present, Email verified and  not adminapproved) then `show wait for admin process`

Can anyone help me in `mongoDB` using `mongoose` how to achieve the same operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done quite right till now, you just need to do few more checks.

try this:

```
User.findOne({ Email: req.body.Email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    else if (!user) {
        return res.json("Account with that email address does not exist.");
    }
    else if(!user.EmailVerified){
        return res.json("Please verify your email");
    }
    else if(!user.AdminApproved){
        return res.json("Wait for admin process, Not Admin approved yet!");
    }
})
```